# how to upload large files to pypi?

Tags: pypi, python-packaging

I have a data file, which is about 2.5GB, `.h5`format and I want to upload it to `pypi`. As the limit is only 60MB I compressed the file, with a `.rar` format. When I do the `pip show -f packagename` it shows `data.rar` under the files uploaded. But for the `.py` file to work, it should be in an uncompressed state. How do I deal with this issue? Thank you.

Comment: What is the meaning of this data file, and why do people who want to use your package, need that file?

Comment: It is a file containing datasets, which the users need to have to use the `.py` file. The `.py` file calls the data from the `.h5` file, every time it runs.

Comment: I mean, why can't they just use their own datasets?

Comment: the `.py` file is trained using the datasets in the `.h5` file. So, not everyone is expected to have those datasets. Also in the future, if they are willing to add more datasets it will be useful.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Should I understand that you managed to compress under 60MiB and are now asking how to uncompress it at install time? -- Please show your project directory structure and your packaging files (setup.py, or setup.cfg, or pyproject.toml, etc.).

Comment: Yes, I compressed the `.h5` file to 53 MB and I am asking to uncompress it during run time.